# Minerva timing attack on P-256 in python-ecdsa

Tags: github, security, ecdsa

I received these security warnings from Defendabot of Github Security.
**Severity : High (7.4 / 10)**

> python-ecdsa has been found to be subject to a Minerva timing attack on the P-256 curve. Using the `ecdsa.SigningKey.sign_digest()` API function and timing signatures an attacker can leak the internal nonce which may allow for private key discovery. Both ECDSA signatures, key generation, and ECDH operations are affected. ECDSA signature verification is unaffected. The python-ecdsa project considers side channel attacks out of scope for the project and there is no planned fix.

The Python-ecdsa officially considers side channel attacks to be outside the scope of the project and there are no planned fixes.
https://github.com/tlsfuzzer/python-ecdsa/security/advisories/GHSA-wj6h-64fc-37mp

Is it better to solve this problem?